# Basemap transparency depending on polygon

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, basemap, transparency-opacity

I want to display a basemap outside a polygon with 50% transparency and inside a polygon with 0% transparency. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?
I use ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could duplicate the basemap, set the lower one to 50% transparency and apply [Clip layers in a map](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/clip-layers-in-a-map.htm) on the upper one.

I cannot test this, since I don't have a ArcGIS Pro license

Comment: Yes, I also copied the basemap first. But your approach helps a lot. 
I went into the map properties and with "Clip Layers" "Clip to an outline" I selected my polygons. Then I excluded the basemap from the clip and set the transparency to 50%.
Thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Motti's answer as a starting point there is no need to Clip *anything* you just need to use the masking option and ensure blend it set under transparency.

[image: Screen shot]

I'm masking the top basemap layer by my box featurelayer.